# Проверка логина и пароля JS

Tags: javascript

Возникла ошибка, которую не получается исправить. После ввода даже неправильного пароля, меня все равно пропускает на страницу. Как можно исправить ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="pass.js" charset="windows-1251"></script>
</head>




<body>

<script>
    let userName = prompt("login");

    if (userName == 'Admin') {

        let pass = prompt('Password:');

        if (pass == 'Admin') {
            alert('Welcome!');
        } else if (pass == '' || pass == null) {
            alert('Canceled');
        } else {
            alert('Wrong password');
        }


    } else if (userName == '' || userName == null) {
        alert('Canceled');
    } else {
        alert("Wrong password");
    }
</script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- header -->
    <div id="header">
         <div id="logo"><a href="#">Леонардо Да Винчи</a></div>
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                <li><a href="https://ic.pics.livejournal.com/orfelius/43541730/472332/472332_original.jpg">Шестерня</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8b/Leonardo_da_Vinci_parachute_04659a.jpg">Парашют</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://img.usamodelkina.ru/uploads/posts/2019-11/1574174225_1-2.jpg">Планер</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.kostyor.ru/archives/9-08/images9-08/history.jpg">Водолазный костюм</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://regnum.ru/uploads/pictures/news/2016/04/16/regnum_picture_1460790271258111_normal.jpg">Велосипед</a></li>
                </ul>
          </div>
    </div>      
    <!--end header -->
    <!-- main -->
    <div id="main">
        <div id="sidebar">

          
        </div>

        <div id="text">
          <h1>Детство</h1>
                <p>Леонардо да Винчи родился 15 апреля 1452 года в селении Анкиано близ небольшого городка Винчи, недалеко от Флоренции в «три часа ночи» то есть в 22:30 по современному отсчёту времени[источник не указан 2639 дней]. Примечательна запись в дневнике деда Леонардо, Антонио да Винчи (1372—1468) (дословный перевод): «В субботу, в три часа ночи 15 апреля родился мой внук, сын моего сына Пьеро. Мальчика назвали Леонардо. Его крестил отец Пьеро ди Бартоломео». Его родителями были 25-летний нотариус Пьеро (1427—1504) и его возлюбленная, крестьянка Катерина. Первые годы жизни Леонардо провёл вместе с матерью. Его отец вскоре женился на богатой и знатной девушке, но этот брак оказался бездетным, и Пьеро забрал своего трёхлетнего сына на воспитание. Разлученный с матерью Леонардо всю жизнь пытался воссоздать её образ в своих шедеврах. Жил он в это время у деда.</p>
         <h1>Изобретения</h1>
                <p>Леонардо да Винчи известен в первую очередь как художник, творец знаменитой «Джоконды» и «Тайной вечери». Его современники ценили прежде всего его художественный талант. Но Леонардо обладал и великим инженерным умом, который люди, жившие с ним в одно время, оценить не могли. Видимо потому, что большинство изобретений да Винчи невозможно было воплотить в жизнь с помощью инструментов XV - XVI веков. А если бы изобретения Леонардо были реализованы, то по средневековым улицам ездили бы автомобили, в небе парили летательные аппараты, а в средневековых сражениях применялись танки и пулеметы.
 </p>
                <ul>
                  <li>Планер </li>
                  <li>Шестерня.</li>
                  <li>Водолазный костюм</li>
                  <li>Велосипед</li>
                  <li>Парашют</li>
                </ul>
          <h1>Последние годы и смерть</h1>
                <p>За два года до смерти у мастера онемела правая рука, и он с трудом передвигался без посторонней помощи. Третий год жизни в Амбуазе Леонардо провёл в постели. 23 апреля 1519 года он оставил завещание, а 2 мая, на 68-м году жизни, скончался в окружении учеников и своих шедевров в замке Кло-Люсе.</p>
                <p>По словам Вазари, да Винчи умер на руках короля Франциска I, своего близкого друга. Эта малодостоверная, но распространённая во Франции легенда нашла отражение в полотнах Энгра, Ангелики Кауфман и многих других живописцев. Леонардо да Винчи был похоронен в замке Амбуаз. На могильной плите была выбита надпись: «В стенах этого монастыря покоится прах Леонардо да Винчи, величайшего художника, инженера и зодчего Французского королевства».

Основным наследником был сопровождавший Леонардо ученик и друг Франческо Мельци, который в последующие 50 лет оставался главным распорядителем наследства мастера, включавшего (кроме картин) инструменты, библиотеку и не менее 50 тысяч оригинальных документов на различные темы, из которых до наших дней сохранилась лишь треть. Другому ученику Салаи и слуге досталось по половине виноградников Леонардо.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end main -->
    <!-- footer -->
    <div id="footer">
    <div id="left_footer">&copy; Тут нет ничего интересного</div>
    <div id="right_footer">

<a href="http://www.realitysoftware.ca/website-design.html"></a> Привет) <a href="http://www.realitysoftware.ca"></a>
<div style="display:none;"><a href="http://free-templates.ru">Хочу спать</a></div>

    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end footer -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А где запрет на "допуск" к странице?

Answer (score 0):

В коде нет ошибок, он работает так как должен, всё хорошо..
За исключением того, что ***так никто не делает***, но не об этом.

Я не вижу ничего, чтобы "запретить" вход на страницу, когда логин или пароль - неверный.

---

Я сделал функцию `AccessDenied()`, в которой меняю HTML содержимое `body` на текст **Доступ запрещён**, тем самым "запрещая" доступ к содержимому страницы.
А вызов этой функции добавлен в условие, где логин или пароль не верный.

```js
let userName = prompt("login");

if (userName == 'Admin') {

  let pass = prompt('Password:');

  if (pass == 'Admin') {
    alert('Welcome!');
  } else if (pass == '' || pass == null) {
    alert('Canceled');
  } else {
    alert('Wrong password');
    AccessDenied();
  }


} else if (userName == '' || userName == null) {
  alert('Canceled');
} else {
  alert("Wrong password");
  AccessDenied();
}

function AccessDenied() {
  document.body.innerHTML = 'Доступ запрещён!';
  document.body.style.cssText = `
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #fff;
    color: red;
    font-size: 20vh;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1;
  `;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <!-- header -->
  <div id="header">
    <div id="logo"><a href="#">Леонардо Да Винчи</a></div>
    <div id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://ic.pics.livejournal.com/orfelius/43541730/472332/472332_original.jpg">Шестерня</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8b/Leonardo_da_Vinci_parachute_04659a.jpg">Парашют</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://img.usamodelkina.ru/uploads/posts/2019-11/1574174225_1-2.jpg">Планер</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.kostyor.ru/archives/9-08/images9-08/history.jpg">Водолазный костюм</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://regnum.ru/uploads/pictures/news/2016/04/16/regnum_picture_1460790271258111_normal.jpg">Велосипед</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--end header -->
  <!-- main -->
  <div id="main">
    <div id="sidebar">


    </div>

    <div id="text">
      <h1>Детство</h1>
      <p>Леонардо да Винчи родился 15 апреля 1452 года в селении Анкиано близ небольшого городка Винчи, недалеко от Флоренции в «три часа ночи» то есть в 22:30 по современному отсчёту времени[источник не указан 2639 дней]. Примечательна запись в дневнике
        деда Леонардо, Антонио да Винчи (1372—1468) (дословный перевод): «В субботу, в три часа ночи 15 апреля родился мой внук, сын моего сына Пьеро. Мальчика назвали Леонардо. Его крестил отец Пьеро ди Бартоломео». Его родителями были 25-летний нотариус
        Пьеро (1427—1504) и его возлюбленная, крестьянка Катерина. Первые годы жизни Леонардо провёл вместе с матерью. Его отец вскоре женился на богатой и знатной девушке, но этот брак оказался бездетным, и Пьеро забрал своего трёхлетнего сына на воспитание.
        Разлученный с матерью Леонардо всю жизнь пытался воссоздать её образ в своих шедеврах. Жил он в это время у деда.</p>
      <h1>Изобретения</h1>
      <p>Леонардо да Винчи известен в первую очередь как художник, творец знаменитой «Джоконды» и «Тайной вечери». Его современники ценили прежде всего его художественный талант. Но Леонардо обладал и великим инженерным умом, который люди, жившие с ним в
        одно время, оценить не могли. Видимо потому, что большинство изобретений да Винчи невозможно было воплотить в жизнь с помощью инструментов XV - XVI веков. А если бы изобретения Леонардо были реализованы, то по средневековым улицам ездили бы автомобили,
        в небе парили летательные аппараты, а в средневековых сражениях применялись танки и пулеметы.
      </p>
      <ul>
        <li>Планер </li>
        <li>Шестерня.</li>
        <li>Водолазный костюм</li>
        <li>Велосипед</li>
        <li>Парашют</li>
      </ul>
      <h1>Последние годы и смерть</h1>
      <p>За два года до смерти у мастера онемела правая рука, и он с трудом передвигался без посторонней помощи. Третий год жизни в Амбуазе Леонардо провёл в постели. 23 апреля 1519 года он оставил завещание, а 2 мая, на 68-м году жизни, скончался в окружении
        учеников и своих шедевров в замке Кло-Люсе.</p>
      <p>По словам Вазари, да Винчи умер на руках короля Франциска I, своего близкого друга. Эта малодостоверная, но распространённая во Франции легенда нашла отражение в полотнах Энгра, Ангелики Кауфман и многих других живописцев. Леонардо да Винчи был
        похоронен в замке Амбуаз. На могильной плите была выбита надпись: «В стенах этого монастыря покоится прах Леонардо да Винчи, величайшего художника, инженера и зодчего Французского королевства». Основным наследником был сопровождавший Леонардо
        ученик и друг Франческо Мельци, который в последующие 50 лет оставался главным распорядителем наследства мастера, включавшего (кроме картин) инструменты, библиотеку и не менее 50 тысяч оригинальных документов на различные темы, из которых до наших
        дней сохранилась лишь треть. Другому ученику Салаи и слуге досталось по половине виноградников Леонардо.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end main -->
  <!-- footer -->
  <div id="footer">
    <div id="left_footer">&copy; Тут нет ничего интересного</div>
    <div id="right_footer">

      <a href="http://www.realitysoftware.ca/website-design.html"></a> Привет)
      <a href="http://www.realitysoftware.ca"></a>
      <div style="display:none;"><a href="http://free-templates.ru">Хочу спать</a></div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end footer -->
</div>
```

Вы же можете добавить в функцию какое угодно действие, вернуться назад \ на главную или ещё что-то.

Но повторюсь, **так никто не защищает страницу**, это обойти очень легко.